# Exception using `NHibernate.Bytecode.DefaultProxyFactoryFactory`

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nhibernate, mstest

I am trying to get an MSTest unit test running, and I have the following line in my NHibernate config section in `App.config`:

```
<property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.DefaultProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate</property>
```

Whenever I try and run the unit test, I get an exception in the `ClassInitialize` method for the test ficture. The exception is:

> NHibernate.Bytecode.UnableToLoadProxyFactoryFactoryException: Unable
>   to load type 'NHibernate.ByteCode.DefaultProxyFactoryFactory,
>   NHibernate.Bytecode' during configuration of proxy factory class.

and my initializer code is:

```
private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;
private static Configuration _configuration;

[ClassInitialize()]
public static void ProductRepositoryInitialize(TestContext testContext)
{
    _configuration = new Configuration();
    _configuration.Configure();
    _configuration.AddAssembly(typeof(Product).Assembly);
    _sessionFactory = _configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
}
```

Yet the `DefaultProxyFactoryFactory` is available, as I can instantiate in in a console application using the line:

```
NHibernate.Bytecode.DefaultProxyFactoryFactory factory = new DefaultProxyFactoryFactory();
```

So why is NHibernate failing to instantiate, or even find, this type in my unit test class. Is it perhaps the test class initializer is static?

**BREAKING NEWS:**
If I use the same proxy factory but with fluent configuration, I get happiness and joy, and rows inserted into my data store.

```
_factory = Fluently.Configure()
    .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2012)
    .Mappings(m => m.HbmMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Product>())
    .ProxyFactoryFactory<DefaultProxyFactoryFactory>()
    .BuildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have `, NHibernate</property>` in your .config-file? The exception you're getting suggests otherwise.

Comment: @AntonGogolev Yes, that line in my config is exactly as its code excerpt above shows. if you scroll it to the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PascalCase mindset plus IDE autocompletion betrays you ;)

Wrong:

```
<property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.DefaultProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate</property>
```

Correct:

```
<property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.Bytecode.DefaultProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate</property>
```

> Why `Bytecode` doesn't meet the format of the other Namespaces?
>
> Because `Bytcode` is a full word not a composition of words so Pascal or
>   Camel Case doesn't apply here.

Anyway, I am not sure of this but I think that if you omit `factory_class` property in config `DefaultProxyFactoryFactory` is created by default. Could somebody confirm it?

Comment: I have long given up on xml based config in favour of fluent, but I strongly suspect you are correct, based on the code excerpts in my OP. I definitely had `ByteCode` in the XML, and definitely (thanks to autocomplete), had `Bytecode` in the test code where I could instantiate the class. Well spotted.

Answer (score 1):

I may come from issue related to **MsTest** (Vs2012)
See [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19864445/visual-studio-2012-mstest-exe-cannot-load-ado-net-provider-sqlite-nhibernate)

You can also try the [DeploymentItemAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20173/mstest-and-nhibernate)

If it's still failing with **NUnit** may you check that [all NHibernate dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7272855/unable-to-load-proxy-factory-factory-exception) are present in the directory.

Comment: I installed NHibernate using Nuget. The only files in the package are `NHibernate.dll` and `NHibernate.xml`, and in the output folder after build, there are only these two NHibernate files, plus `Iesi.Collections.dll` and `Iesi.Collections.xml`. The `DefaultProxyFactoryFactory` class is supposed to be internal to NHIbernate and require no further dependencies. I will check your link for MSTest, even though I'm on VS2015, bit thank you for trying to help.